# MySQLi Prepare Statement Returning Boolean

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I realize that variations of this question have been asked before. I've looked through many, many answers and haven't found something that fixes this.

I'm building a simple private messaging system and I've been trying to get this insert statement to work all day: (NOTE: the code is separated by lines here for readability only)

```
$query = $conn->prepare(
"INSERT INTO messages (assigned, to, from, subject, body, created)
 VALUES( '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', '?')" );
```

I've tried with quotes and without quotes. I've also tried replacing the created variable with the mysql NOW function:

```
$query = $conn->prepare(
"INSERT INTO messages (assigned, to, from, subject, body)
 VALUES( '?', '?', '?', '?', '?', NOW())" );
```

Nothing works. I've been getting 2 errors depending on whether I have full reporting on or not. It gives me  `Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax;` which hasn't helped and, because the prepare statement returns false and the next line uses it as an object, something along the lines of `boolean cannot be used as an object`.

I'm probably making a dumb mistake somewhere and I can't see the forest for the trees, but nonetheless I've spent way too much time on this.

Comment: Placeholders shouldn't be quoted. In your second query, you're passing along 5 columns but 6 variables. If you don't use the quotes and use the correct number of column/variables, what is the full error that you get? The "Error in your SQL syntax" should also give you the sql query.

Comment: For someone else wondering - backticks was necessary to get this to work. You'll find the answer in the link to the duplicate, however it's a long post.

Comment: `To` and `From` are reserved words. I had missed that.